# TextView state_pressed/state_focused/state_selected style change

Tags: android, coding-style, textview, selector, pressed

I'm trying to change a TextView style based on its state.
My styles.xml contains:

```
<style name="text_normal_ops">  
    <item name="android:gravity">left</item>  
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_usual_color</item> 
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>  
</style>  
<style name="text_normal_ops_pressed">  
    <item name="android:gravity">left</item>  
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_pressed</item>  
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>  
</style>
```

My selector (`text_ops.xml`)is defined as:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <item android:state_pressed="true" style="@style/text_normal_ops_pressed" />  
    <item android:state_focused="true" style="@style/text_normal_ops_pressed" />  
    <item android:state_selected="true" style="@style/text_normal_ops_pressed" />  
    <item style="@style/text_normal_ops"/>  
</selector>
```

But when I apply this to my textview (`style="@drawable/text_ops"`) it does not work.
Any tips?
Thanks

Comment: have you kept ur styles.xml in res->values folder???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In android as per my knowledge there is only two state-list 1. Color State List Resource 2. StateListDrawable. If you are using style in it then please recheck the doc

Please check below link for more info

1. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html
2. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: Thanks Maneesh, I guess that was the problem. Do you know of any work-around?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line `style="@drawable/text_ops"` this should be style="@style/text_ops".

I haven't tried using a selector for styles but it would be cool if it works that way.

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean. I also think it is kind of weird to put the __styles__ selector file in the __drawables__ folder, but I don't think it is possible to include the selector inside `values/styles.xml`.