# performItemClick in ListView doesn't highlight item

Tags: android

Then I have a `ListView` set as:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_menu_nav"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="#fff">
</ListView>
```

The adapter is set as:

```
navMenu = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.list_menu_nav );
navMenu.setAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>( this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    menuList ) );
```

When I touch in an item, it gets a white background (as I set). But, when I performClick to a item as below, it is selected but doesn't get the white background.

```
navMenu.performItemClick( navMenu.getChildAt( 1 ), 1, navMenu.getAdapter().getItemId( 1 ) );
```

I know it is selected because everything else works as expected (listener called, `getCheckedItemPosition` returns correct value).

What is the correct approach in this case? Substitute the layout for a custom one and make by myself the highlightening or is there a way using the same default layout?

Comment: Maybe you need to `invalidate` item before performing click.

Comment: I tested it. It doesn't work too, `navMenu.invalidate()` and `navMenu.requestLayout()` after performClick. :\

Comment: @EugenMartynov Supposedly `listSelector` marks what is selected in the list. Following what you're saying, maybe android team should change the name to something like `listSelectorForUserClicks`.

Comment: Use a `selector` then.

Answer (score 1):

You have just `TextView` according to this:

- https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml

So this behaviour is expected. You have to create own layout for item element to customise selected state. Take a look here:

- [Android - Textview change color on changing of state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336218/android-textview-change-color-on-changing-of-state)
- [TextView state_pressed/state_focused/state_selected style change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064707/textview-state-pressed-state-focused-state-selected-style-change)

Answer (score 0):

The `setSelection`, `setItemChecked`, `performItemClick`, extending `ListView` or whatever you are thinking to do, **is not possible**. The `AbsListView` uses a private method to do it called `positionSelector`. That is only called inside others private methods and checked to make sure there was an user interaction before calling positionSelector.

The only workaround you can do is force a touch event:

```
View temp = navMenu.getChildAt( 1 );
navMenu.onTouchEvent( MotionEvent.obtain( SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), 
    SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, temp.getX(), temp.getY(), 0 ) );
```

Comment: What a magic. It have error return error. But I surround with try catch..It worked for me with exception..